# How to remove headers/footers from full page images

Tags: graphics

So I have images in my book that I want to take up a whole page. I don't want it to leave a massive gap in the text, so I'm not going to put a page break between it and the text, but I do want it to appear in a particular location in the text (but not too concerned with it being in the exact location, as that would create a large gap in the text).

I can work this fine with the following code. However, it does also include a header. I can't use `\pagestyle{empty}`, because it will apply that to the entire section, and I can't use `\thispagestyle{empty}` because I can't know where it will appear.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam elementum diam eu blandit rutrum. Donec facilisis, eros quis vehicula laoreet, ipsum ipsum maximus ex, non auctor magna magna non felis. Curabitur elementum vel nisl non fringillaVestibulum massa augue, accumsan ut ligula nec, tincidunt facilisis libero. Suspendisse eget magna lectus. Nullam turpis lectus, dictum quis elit nec, efficitur sollicitudin ligulaIn hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce neque leo, vestibulum eu dapibus vitae, feugiat at lectus. Maecenas a maximus nisl. Donec elit dolor, pharetra nec felis ut, bibendum gravida nibh. Nulla sagittis ut metus vitae bibendum. Nulla quam lorem, interdum elementum mi eu, vestibulum interdum mi. Cras maximus placerat eros, vitae vulputate eros vehicula et. Aliquam et tellus non nulla dictum malesuada. Nunc luctus nisi diam. Curabitur dapibus sem odio, in feugiat ante consectetur nec.


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{test}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

Fusce consequat finibus leo, ut vulputate turpis cursus ac. Ut pretium tellus sapien, et congue eros consectetur ac. Etiam sollicitudin non tortor sit amet luctus. Cras nec metus at elit imperdiet ornare. Praesent elementum sagittis congue. Sed congue vulputate velit, congue tristique metus porta sit amet. Nullam sit amet turpis pretium, dignissim augue vehicula, semper nisl. Nulla vel dictum nulla. Quisque erat nibh, accumsan sit amet lorem sit amet, aliquetegestas nisl. Nullam ultrices aliquet turpis in tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Aenean convallis eu nibh sit amet lacinia. Aenean in ipsum quis augue ultrices facilisis.

Curabitursit amet dui vehicula, egestas quam ut, venenatis eros. Ut eu posuere nulla. Fusce dictum dui sit amet maximus sodales. Pellentesque ante magna, consequat vel justo nec, efficitur aliquam nulla. Vestibulum scelerisque in metus sit amet fermentum. Vivamus id massa vitae libero congue sodales. Ut mollis orci et purus mollis, eget egestas lacus pulvinar. Curabitur eget mi nec urna fringilla malesuada. Nullam eu eros at urnaposuere consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus eget ex ligula. Pellentesque tempor est eget nibh elementum, suscipit commodo urna sollicitudin. Proin finibus arcu ut odio lobortis scelerisque non vel metus. Fusce pellentesque sapien sed massa aliquam, in elementum elit posuere.

\end{document}
```

Edit:

This has been partially answered, and I have come up with the following code, but it does not get rid of the footer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CE]{\nouppercase{\itshape\small TITLE}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\nouppercase{\itshape\small AUTHOR}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\small\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam elementum diam eu blandit rutrum. Donec facilisis, eros quis vehicula laoreet, ipsum ipsum maximus ex, non auctor magna magna non felis. Curabitur elementum vel nisl non fringillaVestibulum massa augue, accumsan ut ligula nec, tincidunt facilisis libero. Suspendisse eget magna lectus. Nullam turpis lectus, dictum quis elit nec, efficitur sollicitudin ligulaIn hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce neque leo, vestibulum eu dapibus vitae, feugiat at lectus. Maecenas a maximus nisl. Donec elit dolor, pharetra nec felis ut, bibendum gravida nibh. Nulla sagittis ut metus vitae bibendum. Nulla quam lorem, interdum elementum mi eu, vestibulum interdum mi. Cras maximus placerat eros, vitae vulputate eros vehicula et. Aliquam et tellus non nulla dictum malesuada. Nunc luctus nisi diam. Curabitur dapibus sem odio, in feugiat ante consectetur nec.


\begin{figure}
 \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[color=white] at (current page.center){\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}};
\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{test}
\end{figure}

Fusce consequat finibus leo, ut vulputate turpis cursus ac. Ut pretium tellus sapien, et congue eros consectetur ac. Etiam sollicitudin non tortor sit amet luctus. Cras nec metus at elit imperdiet ornare. Praesent elementum sagittis congue. Sed congue vulputate velit, congue tristique metus porta sit amet. Nullam sit amet turpis pretium, dignissim augue vehicula, semper nisl. Nulla vel dictum nulla. Quisque erat nibh, accumsan sit amet lorem sit amet, aliquetegestas nisl. Nullam ultrices aliquet turpis in tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Aenean convallis eu nibh sit amet lacinia. Aenean in ipsum quis augue ultrices facilisis.

Curabitursit amet dui vehicula, egestas quam ut, venenatis eros. Ut eu posuere nulla. Fusce dictum dui sit amet maximus sodales. Pellentesque ante magna, consequat vel justo nec, efficitur aliquam nulla. Vestibulum scelerisque in metus sit amet fermentum. Vivamus id massa vitae libero congue sodales. Ut mollis orci et purus mollis, eget egestas lacus pulvinar. Curabitur eget mi nec urna fringilla malesuada. Nullam eu eros at urnaposuere consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus eget ex ligula. Pellentesque tempor est eget nibh elementum, suscipit commodo urna sollicitudin. Proin finibus arcu ut odio lobortis scelerisque non vel metus. Fusce pellentesque sapien sed massa aliquam, in elementum elit posuere.
Fusce consequat finibus leo, ut vulputate turpis cursus ac. Ut pretium tellus sapien, et congue eros consectetur ac. Etiam sollicitudin non tortor sit amet luctus. Cras nec metus at elit imperdiet ornare. Praesent elementum sagittis congue. Sed congue vulputate velit, congue tristique metus porta sit amet. Nullam sit amet turpis pretium, dignissim augue vehicula, semper nisl. Nulla vel dictum nulla. Quisque erat nibh, accumsan sit amet lorem sit amet, aliquetegestas nisl. Nullam ultrices aliquet turpis in tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Aenean convallis eu nibh sit amet lacinia. Aenean in ipsum quis augue ultrices facilisis.
Fusce consequat finibus leo, ut vulputate turpis cursus ac. Ut pretium tellus sapien, et congue eros consectetur ac. Etiam sollicitudin non tortor sit amet luctus. Cras nec metus at elit imperdiet ornare. Praesent elementum sagittis congue. Sed congue vulputate velit, congue tristique metus porta sit amet. Nullam sit amet turpis pretium, dignissim augue vehicula, semper nisl. Nulla vel dictum nulla. Quisque erat nibh, accumsan sit amet lorem sit amet, aliquetegestas nisl. Nullam ultrices aliquet turpis in tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Aenean convallis eu nibh sit amet lacinia. Aenean in ipsum quis augue ultrices facilisis.
Fusce consequat finibus leo, ut vulputate turpis cursus ac. Ut pretium tellus sapien, et congue eros consectetur ac. Etiam sollicitudin non tortor sit amet luctus. Cras nec metus at elit imperdiet ornare. Praesent elementum sagittis congue. Sed congue vulputate velit, congue tristique metus porta sit amet. Nullam sit amet turpis pretium, dignissim augue vehicula, semper nisl. Nulla vel dictum nulla. Quisque erat nibh, accumsan sit amet lorem sit amet, aliquetegestas nisl. Nullam ultrices aliquet turpis in tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Aenean convallis eu nibh sit amet lacinia. Aenean in ipsum quis augue ultrices facilisis.
Fusce consequat finibus leo, ut vulputate turpis cursus ac. Ut pretium tellus sapien, et congue eros consectetur ac. Etiam sollicitudin non tortor sit amet luctus. Cras nec metus at elit imperdiet ornare. Praesent elementum sagittis congue. Sed congue vulputate velit, congue tristique metus porta sit amet. Nullam sit amet turpis pretium, dignissim augue vehicula, semper nisl. Nulla vel dictum nulla. Quisque erat nibh, accumsan sit amet lorem sit amet, aliquetegestas nisl. Nullam ultrices aliquet turpis in tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Aenean convallis eu nibh sit amet lacinia. Aenean in ipsum quis augue ultrices facilisis.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use [p] and the floatpag package.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the foot empty on float pages so replace

```
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\small\thepage}
```

by

```
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\small\thepage}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things `\afterpage` does better than a float, and `\thispagestyle` is one of them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CE]{\nouppercase{\itshape\small TITLE}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\nouppercase{\itshape\small AUTHOR}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\small\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1]

\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {\node at (current page.center)
    {\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image}};}
\newpage}

\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. However, for some reason when having a separate preamble file, I needed to use the term \input{preamble} rather than \include{preamble} I'm not sure why, or even what the difference was, but when using the \include command, it shunted the image off the page.

Comment: \include causes an immediate \clearpage, whicdh isn't allowd in the preamble.

Comment: @JRCSalter never use `\include` in the preamble

Answer (score 0):

The first one is of type `fullpage` (textwidth and -height) and the second one is of type `FULLPAGE` (paperwidth and -height).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    
\blindtext  
    
\hvFloat[fullpage,separatorLine=false]{figure}{\includegraphics[FullPage]{tiger}}{}{}
    
\blindtext

\hvFloat[FULLPAGE,separatorLine=false]{figure}{\includegraphics[FULLPAGE]{tiger}}{}{}

\Blindtext  
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]